# k-means clustering with constraint based on the node values

Tags: constraints, cluster-analysis, k-means

Maybe I'm missing something as this seems to be a simple problem, but I looked this up online and haven't found anything in the literature.

Basically what I need to do is to do a clustering of a set of destination cities based on their location (so latitude/longitude as features of each node, Euclidean distances for the similarity metric), with fixed number of clusters. All seems good and a k-means would do the trick. However, I have the following constraint for each cluster: Every city (node) has a corresponding value assigned to it, and the sum of these values in each cluster should not exceed a fixed threshold (same threshold for all clusters). Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: That is a **knapsack** type of problem rather than a clustering problem. Also, don't use k-means on latitude/longitude.

Comment: No this is not a knapsack problem. It is just clustering with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

-You could instead use *rpart* as a clustering, and use weights and the minbucket option. However the clusters, which predict will give you will be rectangulars.

-You could have a look at the source code which I found on
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/18689414/ :

```
kmeans <-
function(x, centers, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1,
         algorithm = c("Hartigan-Wong", "Lloyd", "Forgy", "MacQueen"))
{
    do_one <- function(nmeth) {
        Z <-
            switch(nmeth,
                   { # 1
                       Z <- .Fortran(C_kmns, x, m, p,
                                centers = centers,
                                as.integer(k), c1 = integer(m), integer(m),
                                nc = integer(k), double(k), double(k), integer(k),
                                double(m), integer(k), integer(k),
                                as.integer(iter.max), wss = double(k),
                                ifault = 0L)
                       switch(Z$ifault,
                              stop("empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers",
                                   call.=FALSE),
                              warning(gettextf("did not converge in %d iterations",
                                               iter.max), call.=FALSE, domain =NA),
                              stop("number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)",
                                   call.=FALSE)
                              )
                       Z
                   },
                   { # 2
                       Z <- .C(C_kmeans_Lloyd, x, m, p,
                               centers = centers, as.integer(k),
                               c1 = integer(m), iter = as.integer(iter.max),
                               nc = integer(k), wss = double(k))
                       if(Z$iter > iter.max)
                           warning("did not converge in ",
                                  iter.max, " iterations", call.=FALSE)
                       if(any(Z$nc == 0))
                           warning("empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers", call.=FALSE)
                       Z
                   },
                   { # 3
                       Z <- .C(C_kmeans_MacQueen, x, m, p,
                               centers = as.double(centers), as.integer(k),
                               c1 = integer(m), iter = as.integer(iter.max),
                               nc = integer(k), wss = double(k))
                       if(Z$iter > iter.max)
                           warning("did not converge in ",
                                   iter.max, " iterations", call.=FALSE)
                       if(any(Z$nc == 0))
                           warning("empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers", call.=FALSE)
                       Z
                    })
        Z
    }
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    m <- as.integer(nrow(x))
    if(is.na(m)) stop("invalid nrow(x)")
    p <- as.integer(ncol(x))
    if(is.na(p)) stop("invalid ncol(x)")
    if(missing(centers))
    stop("'centers' must be a number or a matrix")
    nmeth <- switch(match.arg(algorithm),
                    "Hartigan-Wong" = 1,
                    "Lloyd" = 2, "Forgy" = 2,
                    "MacQueen" = 3)
    if(length(centers) == 1L) {
    if (centers == 1) nmeth <- 3
    k <- centers
        ## we need to avoid duplicates here
        if(nstart == 1)
            centers <- x[sample.int(m, k), , drop = FALSE]
        if(nstart >= 2 || any(duplicated(centers))) {
            cn <- unique(x)
            mm <- nrow(cn)
            if(mm < k)
                stop("more cluster centers than distinct data points.")
            centers <- cn[sample.int(mm, k), , drop=FALSE]
        }
    } else {
    centers <- as.matrix(centers)
        if(any(duplicated(centers)))
            stop("initial centers are not distinct")
        cn <- NULL
    k <- nrow(centers)
        if(m < k)
            stop("more cluster centers than data points")
    }
    if(iter.max < 1) stop("'iter.max' must be positive")
    if(ncol(x) != ncol(centers))
    stop("must have same number of columns in 'x' and 'centers'")
    if(!is.double(x)) storage.mode(x) <- "double"
    if(!is.double(centers)) storage.mode(centers) <- "double"
    Z <- do_one(nmeth)
    best <- sum(Z$wss)
    if(nstart >= 2 && !is.null(cn))
    for(i in 2:nstart) {
        centers <- cn[sample.int(mm, k), , drop=FALSE]
        ZZ <- do_one(nmeth)
        if((z <- sum(ZZ$wss)) < best) {
        Z <- ZZ
        best <- z
        }
    }
    centers <- matrix(Z$centers, k)
    dimnames(centers) <- list(1L:k, dimnames(x)[[2L]])
    cluster <- Z$c1
    if(!is.null(rn <- rownames(x)))
        names(cluster) <- rn
    totss <- sum(scale(x, scale = FALSE)^2)
    structure(list(cluster = cluster, centers = centers, totss = totss,
                   withinss = Z$wss, tot.withinss = best,
                   betweenss = totss - best, size = Z$nc),
          class = "kmeans")
}

## modelled on print methods in the cluster package
print.kmeans <- function(x, ...)
{
    cat("K-means clustering with ", length(x$size), " clusters of sizes ",
        paste(x$size, collapse=", "), "\n", sep="")
    cat("\nCluster means:\n")
    print(x$centers, ...)
    cat("\nClustering vector:\n")
    print(x$cluster, ...)
    cat("\nWithin cluster sum of squares by cluster:\n")
    print(x$withinss, ...)
    cat(sprintf(" (between_SS / total_SS = %5.1f %%)\n",
        100 * x$betweenss/x$totss),
    "Available components:\n", sep="\n")
    print(names(x))
    invisible(x)
}

fitted.kmeans <- function(object, method = c("centers", "classes"), ...)
{
    method <- match.arg(method)
    if (method == "centers") object$centers[object$cl, , drop=FALSE]
    else object$cl
}
```

Please note, that the code checks if an improvement happened with these lines:

```
 if((z <- sum(ZZ$wss)) < best) {
        Z <- ZZ
        best <- z
        }
```

Here you can add your constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same principle as KMeans. Iterate in 2-3 until convergence:

1. Assign cities to clusters (randomly)
2. Compute the centroids of clusters
3. Assign points to centroids such that:

   - The sum of distances to points to the assigned centroids are minimized
   - The threshold constraints are respected

In standard KMeans there are no constraints. Hence the second step is performed easily by assigning each point to the closest centroid. Here you will have to solve an optimization problem in step 2. 
It is probably faster if you just model it as an integer programming problem. [OR Tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools) has facilities for solving integer programming problems.

[Here](https://github.com/Behrouz-Babaki/MinSizeKmeans#constrained-k-means-with-weighted-instances) is a python implementation that does K-means clustering with different constraints, including one with a maximum on total weight of instances in a cluster.